# Como exibir estilo e executar javascript junto com html no Node Js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Comecei a aprender node js, mas enfrento um problema ao renderizar um projeto composto por: Html,css e javascript. O html é enviado e abre, mas o css não funciona assim como o javascript.

codigo node:

```
var express = require("express");
app = express();

app.get("/", function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/index.html")
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/estilo.css")
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/script.js")
})


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: O express só envia um arquivo. Você pode usar src e o link pra o estilo.css e o script.js no index.html

Comment: No caso eu tenho q por o css e o js inline? Mas não tem nenhum jeito de usar o css externamente? Pode ser por outros metodos fora o express

Comment: Você tem que coloca no index.html. Não tem outra forma no express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O servidor serve um ficheiro por pedido. Pode servir mais do que um ao mesmo tempo, mas será com requisições paralelas onde só é enviado um ficheiro por pedido.

Na prática isso quer dizer que deves carregar o ficheiro de html que por sua vez pede ao servidor os outros ficheiros... algo assim:

```
var express = require("express");
app = express();

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/index.html")
})
app.get("/estilo.css", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/estilo.css")
})
app.get("/script.js", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/script.js")
})

app.listen(3000);
```

O express tem uma ferramenta para esses ficheiros estáticos, passas a diretoria, no teu caso `html` e está feito:

```
var express = require("express");
app.use(express.static('html'))
app = express();

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/index.html")
})

app.listen(3000);
```

E caso a rota pedida seja diretamente `/index.html` ele nem corre esse `app.get("/",`.